# How to avoid "unused variable in a for loop" error

Tags: for-loop, go, unused-variables

How to avoid "unused variable in a for loop" error with code like

```
ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Millisecond * 500)
go func() {
    for t := range ticker.C {
        fmt.Println("Tick at", t)
    }
}()
```

if I actually don't use the `t` variable?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You don't need to assign anything, just use `for range`, like this [(on play)](https://play.golang.org/p/Np3GoVB1E5)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Millisecond * 500)
    go func() {
        for range ticker.C {
            fmt.Println("Tick")
        }
    }()
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 2)

}
```

Answer (score 12):

Use a predefined `_` variable. It is named "[blank identifier](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#blank)" and used as a write-only value when you don't need the actual value of a variable. It's similar to writing a value to `/dev/null` in Unix.

```
for _ = range []int{1,2} {
    fmt.Println("One more iteration")
}
```

> The blank identifier can be assigned or declared with any value of any type, with the value discarded harmlessly. It's a bit like writing to the Unix /dev/null file: it represents a write-only value to be used as a place-holder where a variable is needed but the actual value is irrelevant.

#### Update

From Golang [docs](https://golang.org/doc/go1.4#forrange):

> Up until Go 1.3, for-range loop had two forms

```
for i, v := range x {
    ...
}
```

> and

```
for i := range x {
    ...
}
```

> If one was not interested in the loop values, only the iteration itself, it was still necessary to mention a variable (probably the blank identifier, as in for _ = range x), because the form

```
for range x {
   ...
}
```

> was not syntactically permitted.
>
> **This situation seemed awkward, so as of Go 1.4 the variable-free form is now legal. The pattern arises rarely but the code can be cleaner when it does.**

Comment: [Go 1.4](https://golang.org/doc/go1.4#forrange) removed the need for this.  `for range <range>` is perfectly valid syntax now.

Comment: If `range` returns two variables and you only need one of them, do `for _, y in range <range>`.